# Set values NA from first occurence of Pattern to end

Tags: r

Is there a faster/ shorter way to set values after and including match to NA ?

```
vec <- 1:10;vec[c(3,5,7)]<-c(NA,NaN,"remove")
#"1"      "2"      NA       "4"      "NaN"    "6"      "remove" "8"      "9"      "10"
```

Desired Outcome:

```
#"1"      "2"      NA       "4"      "NaN"    "6"      NA       NA       NA       NA
```

My code:

```
vec[{grep("^remove$",vec)[1]}:length(vec)]<-NA
```

Please note:

In that case, we assume there will be a "remove" element prominent. So the solution does not have to take care of the case that there isn't any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to stop searching after the first match is found:

```
m = match("remove", vec) - 1L
if (is.na(m)){
  vec 
} else {
  c(head(vec, m), rep(vec[NA_integer_], length(vec)-m))
}
```

You'd have to have a pretty large vector to notice a speed difference, though, I guess. Alternately, this might prove faster:

```
m = match("remove", vec)
if (!is.na(m)){
  vec[m:length(vec)] <- NA 
}
```

Comment: probably for large vectors your first approach is the CPU fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is shorter or faster but here is one alternative :

```
vec[which.max(vec == "remove"):length(vec)] <- NA
vec
#[1] "1"   "2"   NA    "4"   "NaN" "6"   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Here , we find the first occurrence of "remove" using `which.max` and then add `NA`'s till the end of the vector.

---

OP has mentioned that there is a "remove" element always present so we need not take care of other case however, in case we still want to keep a check we can add an additional condition.

```
inds <- vec == "remove"
if (any(inds)) {
  vec[which.max(inds) : length(vec)] <- NA
}
```

Comment: What about the zero-matches case? I mean `vec = "don't remove me!"; vec[which.max(vec == "remove"):length(vec)] <- NA; vec`

Comment: This is a nice way to approach it. +1

Comment: @Onyambu nope this wouldn't work if there is no match as Frank illustrated, same goes with your solution.

Comment: @zx8754 not even mine would work. Let's assume there is a "remove" element for sure!

Comment: @AndreElrico That is a bad mindset to solve a problem. This might work for you, but useless for others with similar problem.

Comment: @Andre You can edit your question with that info to deter downvoters on answers that assume it if you want

Comment: @zx8754 how is it a bad mindset, doing the most general thing always is not necessarily good. The question implies there is a `"remove"` element. More robust answers may mention that they are, but others aren't "bad" unless OP clearly states these cases should be supported.

Comment: there, OP just edited to confirm that there will always be a `"remove"` element.

Comment: @Frank , zx8754 oops sorry, I just assumed there would always be "remove" element but no harm covering all the cases. Thanks :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Well, such defensive programming is good practice in my work anyways (since someone, maybe me, will eventually pass input that violates my implicit assumptions, leading to avoidable mayhem at some point later in the code). Maybe with one-off scripts it's not a big deal.

Comment: Sure, I'm all for good practices but as OP is asking for efficiency and compacity and downvoted solutions were the fastest and among the most compact that should give a pause to the downvoter.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cumsum` on a logical vector

```
vec[cumsum(vec %in% "remove") > 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also just extend the vec to the desired length:

```
`length<-`(vec[1:(which(vec=="remove")-1)],length(vec))
 [1] "1"   "2"   NA    "4"   "NaN" "6"   NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: changing the "length" property in this situation is ingenious.

Comment: This assumes that there is only one match for "remove" (otherwise `which` will have length greater than 1) and that the match occurs after the first position (since otherwise you'll have vec[1:0] when you should have vec[0]). Could use `which(...)[1]` and `head` instead, though, I think.

Comment: I'll remove mine, it's too similar, I lay it down here though as it was a bit faster on `microbenchmark` : `'length<-'(vec[seq_len(match("remove",vec)-1)],length(vec))`, it matches only the first element but fails if `"remove"` is not there at all.